# Visual Studio Colour Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2008, colors

I've got a custom colour set in Visual Studio and one of the colours when debugging is making things a bit of a misery. Unfortunately I can't figure out which one it is, and when going through and changing all the light background ones, it still remains.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? In this screenshot the current line is yellow, and the caller is the white/cream sort of colour which is the one I want to change...

Thanks very much! :)

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7159/coloursj.png](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/7159/coloursj.png)

Comment: Oh man, me too. I use the same theme, and that annoys me no end.

Comment: Try Joel's suggestion in that case and be ready to give him a +1 :)

Comment: Incidentally several of the display items are background-only and that's why the foreground doesn't match as you noted - you can't set the foreground for this particular display item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors

The display item you want is "Read-Only Region".

Comment: Thanks Joel. For some reason the settings don't grab the correct foreground colour (they say the foreground is always black) which is why I didn't spot it going through the list.

Comment: It always annoyed me as I code under a black theme too - but I only decided to go looking for it when you threw down the challenge. I am happy to have learnt something today =)